# MATLAB gui - How do i generate a colour scale for HSV image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, hsv

I am working on a colour scale that is used to differentiate two standards of my image data. I have image data in RGB and i already converted them to HSV. I managed to find the minimum and maximum values of HSV of each image. Now how do i generate a colour scale in HSV space for the images?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "colour scale". Are you trying to generate a histogram of one or more of the HSV channels?

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding but I'm trying to generate a colorbar in hsv color space but i need to display it on matlab gui..can i do that?

Comment: hsv color space is three-dimensional, a colorbar has only one dimension...

Answer (score 1):

If it is your intention to generate the HSV colour bar, you can create that yourself using the [`hsv`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html#inputs) colormap command.

The colour map looks like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [mathworks.com](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2015a/matlab/ref/colormap_hsv.png))</sub>

You can specify how many total colours `N` from this colour map as input into the function and the output would be a `N x 3` matrix where each row is a floating point (`[0,1]`) RGB tuple where the first row denotes the left most colour and the last row denotes the right most colour in the above image.

As such, the colour map `M` generated from `hsv` would be:

```
M = hsv(N);
```

However, as this is essentially a lookup table / colour map, this would be visualized as an image that is 1 pixel wide (`N x 1`).  You probably want to make this wider so perhaps make the colour bar wider, and so something like this:

```
N = 256; %// Example
height = 50; %// Height of colour bar (in pixels)
M = hsv(N); %// Generate colour map

M = permute(M, [3, 1, 2]); %// Reshape to 1 pixel colour bar that is horizontal
M = repmat(M, [height, 1, 1]); %// Make the colour bar 50 pixels thick

imshow(M); %// Show the image
```

This is what I get:

[image]